# Django ORM query field weight?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, orm, django-views

I'm doing the following query:

```
People.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains='carolina'),
    Q(state__icontains='carolina'),
    Q(address__icontains='carolina'),
)[:9]
```

I want the first results of the query to be the people who is named "Carolina" (and also matches other fields, but name first). The problem is that I don't think is any way to determine a field "weight" or "priority".

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: none of them, the client changed his mind, but the 3 queries is a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do 3 queries for this to work:

```
names_match = People.objects.filter(name__icontains='carolina')[:9]
states_match = People.objects.filter(state__icontains='carolina')[:9]
addresses_match = People.objects.filter(address__icontains='carolina')[:9]

all_objects = list(names_match) + list(states_match) + list(addresses_match)
all_objects = all_objects[:9]
```

There are two problems with this approach, which are fairly easily worked round:

1. It does unnecessary queries (what if `names_match` contained enough items already).
2. It allows for duplicates (what if someone in North Carolina is called Carolina?)

Comment: For case 2, he just has to check duplicates before merging lists.

Comment: Also - be careful of avoiding the second or third queries once you have *enough* results - you'd need to check for duplicates there before determining whether you really have enough.

Comment: For second or third queries he can do a `NOT IN` with the previous results. That should solve a lot of headache.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
qs = People.objects.filter(name__icontains='carolina') | People.objects.filter( Q(state__icontains = 'carolina'), Q(address__icontains='carolina')).distinct()
qs = list(qs)[:9]
```

Or if you want a pure duplicate free list:

```
qs = list(set(qs))[:9] #for a duplicate free list
```